# Least privilege permissions for az storage blob upload-batch

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

Our CI pipeline needs to back up some files to Azure Blob Storage. I'm using the Azure CLI like this: `az storage blob upload-batch -s . -d container/directory --account-name myaccount`

When giving the service principal contributor access, it works as expected. However, I would like to lock down permissions so that the service principal is allowed to add files, but not delete, for example. What are the permissions required for this?

I've created a custom role giving it the same permissions as `Storage Blob Data Contributor` minus delete. This (and also just using the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role directly) fails with a `Storage account ... not found`. Ok, I then proceeded to add more read permissions to the blob service. Not enough, now I'm at a point where it wants to do `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action`. But if I give it access to the storage keys, then what's the point? With the storage keys the SP will have full access to the account, which I want to avoid in the first place. Why is `az storage blob upload-batch` requesting keys and can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've created a custom role giving it the same permissions as Storage Blob Data Contributor minus delete. This (and also just using the Storage Blob Data Contributor role directly) fails with a Storage account ... not found.

I can also reproduce your issue, actually what you did will work. The trick is the [`--auth-mode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload_batch-optional-parameters) parameter of the command, if you did not specify it, it will use `key` by default, then the command will list all the storage accounts in your subscription, when it found your storage account, it will list the keys of the account and use the key to upload blobs.
[image]

However, the `Storage Blob Data Contributor minus delete` has no permission to list storage accounts, then you will get the error.

[image]

To solve the issue, just specify the `--auth-mode login` in your command, then it will use the credential of your service principal to get the access token, then use the token to call the REST API - [Put Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to upload blobs, principle see [Authorize access to blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad).

```
az storage blob upload-batch -s . -d container/directory --account-name myaccount --auth-mode login
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, setting `--auth-mode login` works. You'd think that that would be the default setting. ;-)